# How to solve archive can't be accessed when installing .deb files on ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, software-installation

I've installed the deb fie for mysql version 6 ... and when I've typed :

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-6.deb
```

I've gotten the following error :

```
cannot access archive : no such file or directory 
errors were encountered while processing: mysql-6.deb
```

the result of ls -lah :

```
teeba@ubuntu:~$ ls -lah
total 54K
drwxr-xr-x 24 teeba teeba 1.0K Feb 11 13:10 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root  1.0K Feb  9 07:33 ..
-rw-------  1 teeba teeba  682 Feb 11 12:04 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 teeba teeba  220 Feb  9 07:33 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 teeba teeba 3.5K Feb  9 07:33 .bashrc
drwx------ 20 teeba teeba 1.0K Feb 11 11:29 .cache
drwxrwxr-x  3 teeba teeba 1.0K Feb 10 03:07 .compiz-1
drwx------ 14 teeba teeba 1.0K Feb 11 11:14 .config
drwx------  3 teeba teeba 1.0K Feb  9 15:35 .dbus
drwxr-xr-x  4 teeba teeba 1.0K Feb 11 11:19 Desktop
-rw-r--r--  1 teeba teeba   25 Feb 11 13:10 .dmrc
drwxr-xr-x  2 teeba teeba 1.0K Feb  9 15:35 Documents
drwxr-xr-x  2 teeba teeba 1.0K Feb  9 15:35 Downloads
-rw-r--r--  1 teeba teeba 8.3K Feb  9 07:33 examples.desktop
drwxr-xr-x  2 teeba teeba 1.0K Feb 10 11:03 .fontconfig
drwx------  5 teeba teeba 1.0K Feb 11 13:10 .gconf
-rw-r-----  1 teeba teeba    0 Feb 11 11:06 .gksu.lock
drwx------  4 teeba teeba 1.0K Feb  9 15:35 .gnome2
-rw-------  1 teeba teeba    0 Feb  9 15:39 .goutputstream-7OXQAX
-rw-------  1 teeba teeba    0 Feb 11 11:31 .goutputstream-NHM7AX
-rw-------  1 teeba teeba    0 Feb 10 09:57 .goutputstream-V2USAX
drwxrwxr-x  2 teeba teeba 1.0K Feb 10 08:11 .gstreamer-0.10
-rw-rw-r--  1 teeba teeba  137 Feb 11 13:10 .gtk-bookmarks
dr-x------  2 teeba teeba    0 Feb 11 13:10 .gvfs
-rw-------  1 teeba teeba 2.5K Feb 11 13:10 .ICEauthority
drwxr-xr-x  3 teeba teeba 1.0K Feb  9 15:35 .local
drwx------  3 teeba teeba 1.0K Feb  9 15:35 .mission-control
drwx------  4 teeba teeba 1.0K Feb 10 03:14 .mozilla
drwxr-xr-x  2 teeba teeba 1.0K Feb  9 15:35 Music
-rw-rw-r--  1 teeba teeba    0 Feb 10 08:31 mysql-5.6.deb
drwxr-xr-x  2 teeba teeba 1.0K Feb 11 12:04 Pictures
-rw-r--r--  1 teeba teeba  675 Feb  9 07:33 .profile
drwxr-xr-x  2 teeba teeba 1.0K Feb  9 15:35 Public
drwx------  2 teeba teeba 1.0K Feb 11 13:10 .pulse
-rw-------  1 teeba teeba  256 Feb  9 15:35 .pulse-cookie
drwxr-xr-x  2 teeba teeba 1.0K Feb  9 15:35 Templates
drwx------  4 teeba teeba 1.0K Feb  9 15:36 .thumbnails
drwxr-xr-x  2 teeba teeba 1.0K Feb  9 15:35 Videos
-rw-------  1 teeba teeba   51 Feb 11 13:10 .Xauthority
-rw-------  1 teeba teeba 1.7K Feb 11 13:10 .xsession-errors
-rw-------  1 teeba teeba 5.8K Feb 11 12:05 .xsession-errors.old
```

how do i install .deb files in an easy way ??

**UPDATE :**

I've typed as in the answer :

```
sudo dpkg -i '/home/teeba/Desktop/mysql-workbench-community-6.0.9-1ubu1204-i386.deb'
```

and gotten the following :

```
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-workbench-community:i386.
(Reading database ... 141848 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mysql-workbench-community:i386 (from .../mysql-workbench-community-6.0.9-1ubu1204-i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-workbench-community:i386:
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on libatkmm-1.6-1 (>= 2.22.1).
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4).
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on libcairo2 (>= 1.8.0).
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on libctemplate0.
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1).
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0).
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8).
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on libglibmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 2.32.0).
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on libgnome-keyring0 (>= 2.22.2).
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0).
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 1:2.24.0).
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on liblua5.1-0.
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on libmysqlclient18 (>= 5.5.13-1).
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.18.0).
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on libpangomm-1.4-1 (>= 2.27.1).
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on libpcre3 (>= 8.10).
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on libpcrecpp0 (>= 7.7).
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on libpython2.7 (>= 2.7).
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.0.2).
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.5.9).
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.6).
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on libtinyxml2.6.2.
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on libuuid1 (>= 2.16).
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on libx11-6.
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on libxml2 (>= 2.7.4).
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on libzip2 (>= 0.10).
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on python-paramiko.
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on python-pexpect.
 mysql-workbench-community:i386 depends on python-pysqlite2.
dpkg: error processing mysql-workbench-community:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-workbench-community:i386
teeba@ubuntu:~$
```

There is a problem in dependencies... how to solve that ??

Comment: can you please paste the result of "ls -lah" from the terminal there you tried this?

Comment: I've updated my question and posted the result :)

Comment: Where did you get the .deb from? - the problem is probably due to it being the wrong version.

Comment: what should i do now ?? download the older version ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem that the mysql workbench You've downloaded is for 32 bit ubuntu 12.04.

If your ubuntu is 64 bit you should download the 64bit version of mysql workbench from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQLGUITools/mysql-workbench-community-6.0.9-1ubu1204-amd64.deb)

if you issue the command

```
uname -a
```

in the terminal you should see something written like this:

> 3.2.0-58-generic #88-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 3 17:37:58 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Then the key is x86_64 means that this is a 64bit OS

Comment: where he mentioned the output of `uname -a` command?

Comment: @AvinashRaj he didn't yet mentioned that output

Comment: don't provide the answer by your assumption.

Comment: @AvinashRaj it's not only an assumption. If you read the huge number of dependencies you will notice that there is something wrong. I know workbench is not so dependent. So I realized that architecture is the problem. If I found that this is wrong I will delete my answer immediately

Comment: @AvinashRaj  this is the output : Linux ubuntu 3.11.0-15-generic #25~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:39:31 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @kamil : see the output please

Comment: @Akari kamil's answer is the right one.Try to download 64 bit package.

Comment: @kamil : I think that i downloaded 32 bit ubuntu and my windows is 32 bit ... I'm confused but i will try ur answer ... and back if there will be a problems ... thanks alot kamil thanks alot Avinash

Comment: @Akari Welcome. I hope I answered your question

Answer (score 2):

### Method 1

Right-click on the file and select 'Open With Ubuntu Software Centre':
[image: Right-click on the file and select 'Open With Ubuntu Software Centre']

### Method 2a

Select and copy the file

Open terminal, and type:

```
sudo dpkg -i
```

Then right-click and 'Paste Filenames' - you should get something like this, with no `%20`s, and in quotes `'`:

```
sudo dpkg -i '/home/wilf/Downloads/dropbox_1.6.0_i386.deb'
```

### Method 2b

Change to the directory* the `.deb` file is in - if was in `Downloads` in the home folder:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

or in the `Firefox` directory, in the `Downloads` folder:

```
cd ~/Downloads/Firefox
```

You should be able to tell if the terminal is in the right directory if your run this:

```
ls | grep -i deb
```

and the filename appears in the output:

```
wilf@comp:~/Downloads$ ls | grep -i deb
dropbox_1.6.0_i386.deb
```

you should be able to run it as:

```
sudo dpkg -i dropbox_1.6.0_i386.deb
```

Note also the name of directory the terminal is currently in appears in the command prompt to the right of your username & the computer's hostname. The terminal in which you running `dpkg` needs to be in the same sirecotry as the `.deb` file.

<sub>*By default the terminal is 'in' the home directory, which is represented by `~`</sub>

Comment: @Akari are you sure your distribution is 32 bit. Try uname -a and give us the result

Comment: @kamil I'm a beginner on ubuntu and i don't know what do mean by : uname -a .. can u clarify more please

Comment: open the terminal, write the following command: uname -a, and simply copy/paste the result here

Comment: ok ... I'll be right back ...

Comment: @kamil ::: this is the result : Linux ubuntu 3.11.0-15-generic #25~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:39:31 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux