# how to solve apt: command not found

Tags: apt

I tried so many times to install mysql workbench and I faced many problems. The last one is in dependencies. I tried to solve that by typing:

```
sudo apt -get install mysql-workbench-community-6.0.9-1ubu1204-i386.deb
```

But unfortunately I got this error:

> sudo: apt: command not found

How can I do that with Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: its not the proper way of installing deb file.

Comment: where was `mysql-workbench-community-6.0.9-1ubu1204-i386.deb` file?

Comment: can you help me please by providing me by the proper way .... because because i spent 3 days to install mysql workbench on ubunto 12.04 and i failed :( !!!!

Comment: in the download directory

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The proper command is `apt-get` instead of `apt get`.

You need to be careful when typing commands, as you can do lots of damage. For example, typing `mkfs.ext3 /dev/sda` instead of `mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb` will destroy all data on that drive.

THe command's proper form is:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

The above command fetches mysql workbench from the official Ubuntu repository. A repository is a web server containing many programs or files.

It seems like you already downloaded the `.deb` file associated with the mysql-workbench package, so you can just install it by `cd /path/where/you/downloaded/file/` and then running command:

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-workbench-community-6.0.9-1ubu1204-i386.deb
```

**EDIT:** If you have dependency problems, you should try `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: without space between them ?

Comment: @Akari yes my dear. apt-get is a command without spaces

Comment: @Akari both ways mentioned in my answer should work for you. Just try them

Comment: last command will work.

Comment: @Akari Don't forget to Mark it as answer so that the community will make benefit from it

Comment: @kamil he can't upvote because of reputations.

Comment: yes last command work but i had a problems in dependences when i used it first ... see my problem here: [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/419640/how-to-solve-archive-cant-be-accessed-when-installing-deb-files-on-ubuntu)

Comment: @kamil ok i will do that thank u>> but please see my problem which is provided in the link ...

Comment: @Akari I am commenting on your other question. But If your computer is online please put in your terminal: sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench

Comment: @kamil this is the big problem for me because there is an problem with the network connection on ubuntu because I use a mobile broadband network and there is a problems with the dongle :( is there a way to fix the problems but not online :( ??

Comment: @Akari yes I am here to help. but did you put the command uname -a and tell me the result

Comment: I've posted the result in a comment on the other qustion